# HTML5 Video in Chrome/PC

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

Been working with HTML5 video for a bit now - I found that in order to cover all my bases for browsers, I need 3 formats for my html5 video player: .mp4, .ogv, and .webm (with a flash player fallback of course). Been converting using a combination of wondershare and firefogg, and I've had great success with it.

However, I recently discovered that Chrome/PC is playing the audio from the video, but the video itself isn't rendering - for all 3 formats. It's fine on Safari/Mac, FF/Mac, Chrome/Mac, FF/PC, and IE/PC - but not Chrome/PC. I've determined that this isn't an issue with my html5 player, but with the videos themselves - accessing the files directly yields the same results, audio with no video. Has anyone else encountered this? Is there a special trick to web-encoding the videos for Chrome 11, or do I need a 4th format?

Comment: How did you encode the video? Do you have a sample online?

Comment: Are you using a very high bitrate?

Answer (score 0):

it'll be a codec problem.
try this when encoding for mp4 format.

video codec : MPEG-4 AVC/H-264
audio codec : Advanced Audio Codec(AAC)